# Htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Hey folks, I'm migrating a website over a to new CMS with a different URL structure, I'd like to have users redirect if a specific part of the link is missing. So if the user goes to www.domain.com/**articles/name_of_article** it'll take them to the old site, however if they go to www.domain.com/ it'll forward them to the subdirectory http://beta.domain.com 
So what I'm trying to accomplish  is to leave the old URLs active as to not lose traffic from old links since migrating those links is impossible because of how the old CMS was coded..but prompt the user to move over to the new site when they land on those pages.

how can this be accomplished via htaccess, any tips will be greatly appreciated?

Regards and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://beta.domain.com/
```

did it

...The answer was a lot simpler than the question hah

Comment: Remember to mark your own answer as the accepted answer - you're allowed to answer yourself.